# PortForwarding eth0 to ppp0

Tags: iptables, routing, port-forwarding, masquerade

I have a RaspberryPi which connects to the internet on eth0 which has static IP, I have installed Squid and I have also enabled 1694 port on my Mikrotik router to be forwarded to 3128 port on my raspberry, so I can use my raspberry as a proxy server. For example, when I test it like this from another device on another internet, it works:

```
$ curl -x MY.STAT.IC.IP:1694 https://wtfismyip.com/text

MY.STAT.IC.IP
```

Now I have add a 3g shield to my Raspberry and I was able to connect to 3g network and now I have internet on ppp0 interface which has a dynamic IP. Now I want to forward all incoming requests to eth0 to be routed over ppp0, so when I do above curl, I get my 3g network IP.

I don't want to use `tcp_outgoing_address` on squid, as it has lots of problems, I want to do port forwarding, and I have done the following but it still returns my static IP.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have tried lots of other iptables forwarding, but none of them worked. I have tried [this bash script](https://gist.github.com/bastosmichael/7830661) (edited ofcourse) but it didn't worked either, I also tried ipt.sh from [this link](https://www.g7smy.co.uk/2014/08/raspberry-pi-as-a-3g4g-router/) which I was sure it would work, but still no success, so, what am I missing?

Comment: With "wifi IP" you mean your 3g network IP, right?

Comment: @AndreasT yes, I will edit it now.

Comment: Can you clarify your intentions? What should be the end-result? If someone external makes a request to your Mikrotik on Port 1694 the proxy should be executing it via the 3g link?

Comment: @AndreasT Yes, Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Check if PI uses the 3g

---

First you have to ensure, that the PI is using the 3g ppp0 connection for outgoing packets.

```
ip route
```

Should output something like:

```
default via XXXXXX dev ppp0
```

Also, doing that curl you mentioned (with the proxy ip set to localhost) on the pi should give you the 3g address.

### 2. Check if local proxying works

After this: Try if local proxying works.
So use a computer in your network, set the PI as proxy and run the curl ip check.
It should also return the 3g IP.

If that works you will have to put a rule into your Mikrotik that masquerades packets to squid as if they were originating from the Mikrotik:

### 3. Make Mikrotik look like the packet origin

So you have to add to your DSTNAT rule an analogous  SRCNAT rule that has `action` set to the MASQUERADE option.

If done right, this will make any packet that gets forwarded to squid by the Mikrotik look like originating from the Mikrotik itself.
Which is a local device.
Which reduces your problem to one already solved above in point **2**.

Comment: When I do ```sudo route add default gw MY.3G.GAT.WAY```, then point 1 and 2 are exactly as you said, I see ```default via XXXXXX dev ppp0``` and when I check curl command with pi proxy on local computer on my network I can see 3g IP. Also, for point 3, I have a NAT rule in Mikrotik but I set ```action``` as dst-nat and I guess it doesn't forward incoming request to my squid? so Can you be more specific with the point 3?

Comment: So, If i get it correct, I should have 2 NAT rules on my mikrotik? a DSTNAT with dst-nat action and to my pi address, and a SRCNAT rule with masquerade action? I didi it, but still when I check online portchecktool.com, it doesn't see my port.

Comment: Yes, it worked! it was a workaround actually, but I am happy that you understand my problem and offered a solution that solved my problem! Thanks.